# Rename columns from external file in R

Tags: r, qualtrics

I have survey data and want to rename each column. I have the new, recoded column names stored as records in a `.csv` file:

```
> new.cols <- read.csv('1.recoded.csv', sep = ',', header = TRUE)
> new.cols
                      new.colname
1                            1.v1
2                            1.v2
3                          1.name
4                            1.v4
5                         1.email
6                            1.v6
...
```

My original column headings are as follows:

```
>names(pre.use.survey)
[1] "ï..V1"            
[2] "V2"               
[3] "V3"               
[4] "V4"               
[5] "V5"               
[6] "V6"
...
```

What I want to iterate through each column name in `pre.use.survey` and rename it to the corresponding record for each column name. This is my code:

```
for (col in names(pre.use.survey)) {
  for (row in new.cols) {
    pre.use$col <- row
  }
}
```

This doesn't do anything, unfortunately. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you want to replace the column names of pre.use.survey with new.colname? I just wanna clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you need is

```
names(pre.use.survey) <- new.cols$new.colname
```

As R is vectorized, you often **don't** need to use for loops.

Comment: Is there any way to do this that specifies the columns in old & new docs? E.g. I want to rename the columns 2:8 from the original survey, using the 1:7 from the new doc, and then the columns 21:30 from the original with 8:17 from the new doc. Is that clear?

Comment: @Gilrob you can use `[` to specify indices. So `names(original)[2:8] <- names(new_doc)[1:7]`, etc.